# Get Updates via RSS - Facebook SyndicationErrorFeed

Tags: facebook, rss

I'm trying to import the RSS from a Facebook page to my website, but when I click on "Get Updates via RSS" on the left side of my page, I'm getting this error:

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=142648432496996&format=rss20

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <rss version="2.0"
           xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
           xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         >
       <channel>
         <title></title>
         <link></link>
         <description></description>
         <language>en-us</language>
         <category domain="Facebook">SyndicationErrorFeed</category>
         <generator>Facebook Syndication</generator><docs>http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification</docs>
         <lastBuildDate>Fri, 02 Dec 2011 05:28:53 -0800</lastBuildDate>
         <webMaster>webmaster@facebook.com</webMaster>
         <item>
           <guid>http://www.facebook.com/feeds/syndication_error.php#bd652632c2b2f78e4d74b708b37cdebb_</guid>
           <title>Erro do RSS do Facebook</title>
           <link>http://www.facebook.com/feeds/syndication_error.php#bd652632c2b2f78e4d74b708b37cdebb_</link>
           <description>This feed URL is no longer valid. Visit this page to find the new URL, if you have access: &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=142648432496996&quot;&gt;http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=142648432496996&lt;/a&gt;</description>
           <pubDate>Fri, 02 Dec 2011 05:28:53 -0800</pubDate>
           <author>Facebook.com</author>
           <dc:creator>Facebook.com</dc:creator>
         </item>
       </channel>
       <access:restriction relationship="allow" xmlns:access="http://www.bloglines.com/about/specs/fac-1.0" />
     </rss>
```

It's does not seem to be consistent. I tested this "Get Updates via RSS" on other pages, it works with some and does not with others (same problem).

I try to check the page permissions, but I didn't find any permission configuration for a page RSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any geographic / demographic restrictions on the page? If there are, you probably won't be able to syndicate it

Comment: I've never seen that message unless the page was limited to users over 18, a certain country, etc. I'd double check your page settings and try it again if i were you

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! The problem was in the age restriction. I removed it. Is there a way to retrieve the rss even with the age restriction? Maybe passing viewer_id in the url?

Comment: No, you'd have to have an access token for that viewer to prove you're able to view content visible to that user - basically this rules out using RSS, you'd have to use the API instead

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

from the results.  If you're trying to get and parse the response, this line interferes.  Currently going through the same trouble, but I've figured it out to the point that I need to get the pages avatar.

Basically, for RSS feeds with valid XML (which you can tell by the formatting/colors when viewing the feed in a browser) you can parse.

But the fb feeds add this line to the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

The first line needs to be the

```
<rss xmlns:content="
```

line.